# Is there a way to re-attach an X Window if my X Server is in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows-10, xorg, hyper-v

I am running an Arch Linux Machine on Hyper-V with Windows X11 Server (VcXsrv) for GUI. It works wonderfully well (since it brings the X Windows as native Window in Windows 10 - I can do <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> etc.; it is almost like Windows 10 my window manager :-)) except for one problem: Windows would "disappears" if I **lock** or **suspend** my machine possibly due to the issue mentioned here: 
[WSL2 X11 programs "disappear"](https://superuser.com/questions/1474559/wsl2-x11-programs-disappear). The worst part is that all the processes are intact.

It seems like TCP/IP is the issue; but why should TCP/IP be a problem if I am in the same machine? Can I make it to **not** disconnect during lock or suspend?

Alternatively, is there anyway to re-attach the X Windows if I can store the Window IDs or something like that? It seems like a trivial problem but no direct solution seems to exist.

I can use `screen` to save my terminal work (but even then the terminal window would be open), but `X` is the problem. I read about `xpra` here [Reattach to lost X11 session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10597/reattach-to-lost-x11-session), but I doubt it can create sessions in Windows?

The steps to reproduce this issue is really simple:

1. Create a VM using Hyper-V.
2. Use Hyper-V's "Connect" to open a console.
3. Start VcXsrv on Windows.
4. Type `DISPLAY=<host.ip.address:0.0> xterm`.
5. Lock or suspend Windows.

What about `disown`ing?

My starting script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

"${@}" &>/dev/null &

disown
```

Could `disown`ing in my starter script be the problem? Once in a while I logout of my Hyper-V's console (especially after starting the GUI programs) - will that be a problem?

Edit: Keeping the Hyper-V's console open will also not solve the problem. Even executing it in foreground without `disown` didn't help.

Comment: WSL2 and the end-user-part of Hyper-V is completely different. In Hyper-V there is no "X Window" thing in Windows side. Can you provide some info about the disappearance of VM window? Did you try to reconnect (not shutdown) the VM from Hyper-V management console?

Comment: @Biswapriyo, I have updated the exact steps I do; it is really simple! I can always connect to the machine using Hyper-V's Management Console using "Connect". Usually, I go to the console and kill all my X processes.

Comment: “but why should TCP/IP be a problem if I am in the same machine?” Because you’re not. VMs (and also WSL2) run as if on a different PC networked to yours. // So, yes, this is exactly like using WSL2.

Comment: Try `xpra` anyway. Its server part will be in Arch, it should survive. Its client part will be in Windows, it may fail or disconnect. But the very purpose of `xpra` is to give us the ability to reconnect after the original connection is terminated (because of client failure, network failure, deliberate action or whatever). As long as the server runs and accepts connections, windows in it should be reachable.