# Disappearing windows - now in wslg

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, xorg, hyper-v, wslg

This is a followup to old questions
[WSL2 X11 programs "disappear"](https://superuser.com/q/1474559/308428) and

[Is there a way to re-attach an X Window if my X Server is in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/1524225/308428)

These are from the pre-wslg era, but now I have the same issue on

```
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.1848
```

(Ubuntu 22.04). I run emacs and GAP from inside emacs in a wslg window, then computer goes to sleep, when I wake it up the window is gone, although all the processes are intact.

Does anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: I've been having the same issue for months now with no solution found. I can say that the connection itself to the x server is not lost because if I tab into the invisible window and press F11 in VSCode to enter full screen, the window appears. Only to disappear again after exiting full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me is this script by the github user [tyingq](https://github.com/tyingq), I found it among the [wslg issues](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/529#issuecomment-954120973):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sx=30
sy=30
for window in $(xdotool search -name .)
do
   xdotool windowmove $window $sx $sy
   xdotool windowunmap $window
   xdotool windowmap $window
   sx=$(($sx + 40))
   sy=$(($sy + 40))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution but a work-around. My version of WSL2 in Windows 11:

```
PS> wsl --version
WSL version: 2.0.9.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2861
```

I'm running emacs from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS WSL. When the emacs window(s) disappear I start second emacs instance (`emacs&`) and the lost window(s) of the first emacs instance re-appear. Then I just quit the second emacs instance and continue working with the first emacs instance.

Answer (score 1):

For me, simply starting another X application, any application, will do the trick. I use `xeyes` for that. Then all windows reappear.

I have also `(server-start)` in my .emacs, and I check the status of the apparently disappeared, invisible emacs from a wsl text console, with `emacsclient -nw .` (the dot belongs to the command).